# PHP: Omitting parts of string enclosed in [] () {}

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to make a rule that can simultaneously remove any parts of the string enclosed with [] () and {} in one go, only leaving any part of it?

For example, if I have a string like this:

```
// Input
$string = 'my(apple)[banana][carrot(orange)]food[supply]';

// Output
$string = 'myfood';
```

I know how to select parts of a string that is enclosed with brackets, but in this case I want to select any parts that isn't enclosed instead.

Here's my current regex where I'm stuck, which I can select the enclosed characters:

```
\[.*?\]|\(.*?\)|\{.*?\}
```

Comment: Okay, how does that regex not work for you? https://3v4l.org/crIqu

Comment: You're right, my regex actually works. I thought it wasn't but it was actually my fault for doing a var_dump above the preg_replace line.

Comment: Since the code works this sounds like a typo, not a coding issue.

Comment: [`[[{(]+[^)\]}]*[)\]}]+`](https://regex101.com/r/x2t6nF/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is work around to achieve this,

```
$string = 'my(apple)[banana][carrot(orange)]food[supply]{test}';
echo preg_replace('/{(.*?)}|\[.*?\]|\([^)]+\)/","",$string);
```

Here is working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ab1f14bee0fee1ec7af71fd55b3607f4897e42a).

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer:

```
  $var = 'my(apple)[banana][carrot(orange)]food[supply]';

  echo preg_replace('/\[.*?\]|\(.*?\)|\{.*?\}/', '', $var);
```

Comment: Your regex is correct but if you compare with my regex, performance wise my regex is almost double better than this.